# Embed API Google Analytics нужна помощь в получении access_token PHP

Tags: php, google-analytics

Добрый день!
Есть у гугла документация по этому вопросу https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/ , но код представлен для python.

Вопрос в следующем - имея "service account" и ключ в json формате, как на стороне сервера получить access_token? Кто сталкивался?

Пытаюсь следовать документации, код такой:

```
require_once APPPATH . "libraries/Google/vendor/autoload.php";
$client = new Google_Client() ;
$client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
$sa = new ServiceAccountCredentials(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
    APPPATH.'libraries/Google/Autofafa-49fafa6d8f2e.json'
);
```

Ошибка **Class 'ServiceAccountCredentials' not found** Это понятно, что класс не найден, сам файл есть и по идее через autoload.php должен подгружаться.

Что делаю не так?

Comment: Написали бы, где можно найти код, который вы пытаетесь использовать. Может класс банально с namespace объявлен.

Comment: Скачано с гита от google. Но там под composer перед классом стоит namespace Google\Auth;

Comment: Так если объявлен в пространстве имён, из этого пространства имён его запрашивать и надо.

Comment: оказывается, они убрали этот класс из новой версии, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался, рабочий код:

```
require_once APPPATH . "libraries/Google/vendor/autoload.php";
$client = new Google_Client() ;
$client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
$client->setAuthConfig(APPPATH.'libraries/Google/111-11.json') ;
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='.APPPATH.'libraries/Google/111-11.json');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly')) ;
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->refreshTokenWithAssertion() ;
$accessToken = $client->getAccessToken() ;
```

А вот описание как изменился алгоритм с прошлой версией https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/UPGRADING.md#google_auth_assertioncredentials-has-been-removed